# Cannot build resteasy from source

Tags: rest, jboss, resteasy

I got the code from github for resteasy. When trying to do an mvn clean install, I am getting the following exception. I would appreciate if someone can point me in the correct path on how to resolve this.

[image]

The error is:

/D:/rnd_work/jboss/resteasy/Resteasy/jaxrs/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/internal/ClientInvocation.java:[154,34] D:\rnd_work\jboss\resteasy\Resteasy\jaxrs\resteasyclient\src\main\java\org\jboss\resteasy\client\jaxrs\internal\ClientInvocation.java:154: type parameters of T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulted the RestEasy developer mailing list and it seems This is a bug fixed in JDK 7[1]. Updating my JDK to the latest JDK 1.7 build, did the trick. Also i put the ant-contrib jar to my classpath variable. Because otherwise the build fail.s